# How to make clickable box

Tags: html, css

I want to make one of my element in menu "Login" as clickable box (with hover effect). I made link as display: block; but there is not enough.

Link to screenshot:
[image: Link to screenshot]

I've problem with blue borders on top and bottom. How to make these borders also as clickable box?

```
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">+48 123 456 789</a></li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
nav li
{
    padding: 7px 0;
}

ul a
{
    color: #006db6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul li:nth-child(5)
{
    background-color: #006db6;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

ul li:nth-child(5) a
{
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
}

ul li:nth-child(5) a:hover
{
    color: #006db6;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: With the css you posted, there are no borders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try in this way (explanations in comments):

```css
nav li
{
    /*padding: 7px 0;*/
}

ul a
{
    color: #006db6;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 0; /* moved from li */
    background-clip: content-box; /* background only for content, without padding */
}

ul li:nth-child(5)
{
    background-color: #006db6;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

ul li:nth-child(5) a
{
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
}

ul li:nth-child(5) a:hover
{
    color: #006db6;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```css
nav {
  float: left;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul a {
    color: #006db6;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px 0;
    background-clip: content-box;
}

ul li:nth-child(5) {
    background-color: #006db6;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

ul li:nth-child(5) a {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
}

ul li:nth-child(5) a:hover {
    color: #006db6;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">+48 123 456 789</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```